# NextJS localstorage add to cart items || Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "0" Client: "2"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

After click "add to cart" i want save items in local storage, I write Hook but this hook have most of issues in usage.

Finally I try in this Hook return all variables, to be simple used in components like:

```
const { cart, cartCount, cartItems, removeItem etc.. } = useCartItems();
```

But now in  page.tsx example I need retrive items like:

```
  const { removeFromCart, clearCart } = useCartItems();
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  // Load cart items from local storage
  const storedCartString = localStorage.getItem('cart');
  const storedCart: ItemType[] = storedCartString ? JSON.parse(storedCartString) : [];
```

Because when I tr load "cart" and then in console log I have empty, because is issue beetwen server side and client side.

Example when I try load cartCount in component:

```
const { cart, cartCount } = useCartItems();
```

Then in return I use:

```
{cartCount}
```

This correct  display counted cart items but with error warning:

```
app-index.js:34 Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "0" Client: "2"
```

Can anyone help me beautify this code to make more friendly and possible use  only hook in pages and componetns like `cartItems, cartCount` etc.

Here is hook code:

```
export const useCartItems = () => {
  // Load cart from localStorage on hook initialization
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(() => {
    try {
      // Check if window is defined (running on the client side)
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        // Attempt to parse the cart from localStorage
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // If there's an error, return an empty array
      console.error('Error loading cart from localStorage:', error);
      return [];
    }
  });

  // Save cart to localStorage whenever it changes
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      // Check if window is defined (running on the client side)
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        // Attempt to save the cart to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving cart to localStorage:', error);
    }
  }, [cart]);

  // Function to add an item to the cart or update its quantity
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    const existingItem = cart.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id);

    if (existingItem) {
      // Update quantity if item already exists in cart
      const updatedCart = cart.map((cartItem) =>
        cartItem.id === item.id ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 } : cartItem
      );
      setCart(updatedCart);
    } else {
      // Add new item to cart if it doesn't exist
      setCart([...cart, { ...item, quantity: 1 }]);
    }
  };

  // Function to clear the entire cart
  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };

  // Function to remove a specific item from the cart
  const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
    const updatedCart = cart.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
    setCart(updatedCart);
  
    // Force reload the page
    window.location.reload();
  };
  // Calculate cart count
  const cartCount = (cart ?? []).length;


  return {
    cart,
    addToCart,
    cartCount,
    clearCart,
    removeFromCart,
  };
};
```

here is my product details add to cart page:

```
const ProductPage = () => {
  const { product, loading, error } = useProductData();
  const { cart, addToCart: addToCartHook, removeFromCart } = useCartItems();
  const [isCartOpen, setIsCartOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedQuantity, setSelectedQuantity] = useState(1);

  const handleAddToCart = (item) => {
    addToCartHook(item);
    setSelectedQuantity((prevQuantity) => {
      addToCart(item.databaseId, prevQuantity);
      return prevQuantity;
    });
  };

  const handleQuantityChange = (newQuantity) => {
    setSelectedQuantity(newQuantity);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cart?.length > 0) {
      setIsCartOpen(true);
    }
  }, [cart]);

  const handleCloseCart = () => {
    setIsCartOpen(false);
  };
```